# How do I play the intro riff from Collective Soul's song Heavy?

Tags: technique, electric-guitar, guitar-effects

[This](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2141/how-can-i-get-a-sound-similar-to-shine-by-collective-soul) question got me all jazzed up about Collective Soul again, so I was spinning through my iTunes library and I hit "Heavy" off Dosage. I have always wondered how to play the beginning riff of that song. I have tried many times to figure it out, but to no avail. I *think* he's using a kill switch, pinky volume knob voodoo, or perhaps some studio trickery. It's not a tremolo--I have a Diamond, which will do almost any trem sound possible, and I still can't emulate it properly.

Has anyone figured that one out or is there a reputable article out there with some tips? Internet tablature does **not** count as a reputable source unless you can convince me otherwise.

Comment: That intro is killer.  I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Every time I've seen them live Dean Roland has triggered the intro from a keyboard he keeps near him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is live, but that part seems to have been sampled for the performance.
[Collective Soul- Heavy Live](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFX2pk-FtEU&feature=related)

The intro tone sounds like Tremolo with studio editing.

Edit:  Tried it out on my Line 6 Flextone Plus.  It's definitely a fast Tremolo and you alternate open E with 12th fret E   I cant write tab very well so I'll put a little note and if someone wants to edit go ahead

0 12 12 0 12 12 0 12 12 0    And you have to time it with the tremolo. the trem has to be fast, I didn't get the BPM, but I set the trem to be quite fast.  Live, if you watch the vids,  they play it as a sample, so it may be something they cant replicate too easily then go into the rest of the song.

Answer (score 1):

I have a trem on my old Zoom 4040 which sounds very like that, it's almost a square wave trem, but with a very slight slope on the verticals. Most tremolo pedals are too gently with the slope.

I'll try to replicate it on my Line-6 - if I can I'll pop the settings up here this weekend.

p.s. Delighted to have been introduced to a band I hadn't heard of. Need to choose which of their works to buy now :-)

Comment: Pick up dosage first, it's the ubiquitous Collective Soul album.

Answer (score 0):

I use whats called a slicer on my BOSS GT10, and it works just fine. Very close without the studio dressings of course.